# Why can't I identify some staves/rings in Rogue?

Tags: rogue

I am playing Rogue (the old ASCII dungeon-crawler, v5.4.4 from the Arch Linux repository). I have played Nethack in the past, but this is my first time trying the original Rogue. For some reason, when I cast a scroll of identify ring, wand or staff, even if I have some rings/staves in my inventory, it says I have nothing appropriate to cast it on and the spell is wasted. Does anyone know why this is? Are those rings/staves not magical then (and therefore useless)?